# $(this).index() Alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following Tabs Function:

```
//Tabs ///
$('.tabs').each(function() {
  var $tabs = $(this);
  $tabs.find('.section-body > div:not(:first-child)').hide().end()
 .find('.section-head a:eq(0)').addClass('active').end()
 .find('.section-head a').on('click', function() {

    $tabs.find('.section-head a').removeClass('active').end()

  .find('.section-body > div:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').show().siblings().hide();
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

It workes, however the `$(this).index()` is clashing with another plugin and the other plugin stops working when the `$(this).index()` is there. Is there a different way to achieve the same tabs results without using $(this).index()?

Here is the HTML if needed:

```
<div class="section tabs">
  <div class="section-head">
    <a>Section A</a>
    <a>Section B</a>
  </div>
  <div class="section-body">
    <div>
      <p>Section A</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Section B</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here is a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qEgg5/1/**

Comment: You could also get the index from your each itself. (if you pass in the first parameter to function) `each(function (index, elem) {})`

Comment: In your maximally complicated example I find it difficult to tell what `$(this)` refers to in the event handler ...

Comment: Associate your navigation and tabs correctly by using links and `id`s, then just select `link.attr('href')`.

Answer (score 2):

You've two solutions

1. Firstly, there shouldn't be any ambiguity. So change the plugin's name. Its easy-peasy.
2. Secondly, if you don't want to do the first, then follow the instructions below:

Before including the plugin, do this:

```
$.fn.myIndex = $.fn.index;
```

What the above does is, it creates a new plugin `myIndex` which is passed the function reference of `index`
And now you can use `$(this).myIndex()` to give the same effect as `$(this).index()` but without ambiguity.

Comment: Can you please show me how I can use the second option in JSfiddle? I have never seen this before

Comment: Please take a look here: http://loai.directory/reiss/profile inspect the element, can you see the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) make use of the parameters passed to the argument of `.each()`:

> .each( function )
>
> ```
> function
> Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )
> A function to execute for each matched element
> ```

Thus it would become:

```
$('.tabs').each(function(idx, elt) {
  var $tabs = $(elt);// $(elt) is equivalent to $(this)
  $tabs.find('.section-body > div:not(:first-child)').hide().end().find('.section-head a:eq(0)').addClass('active').end().find('.section-head a').on('click', function() {
    $tabs.find('.section-head a').removeClass('active').end().find('.section-body > div:eq(' + idx + ')').show().siblings().hide();
    $(elt).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

[Further info here](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just simply use jQuery notation

```
jQuery(this).index();
```

or if really needed put jquery to noConflict mode

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

now $ control is returned to other library. See more here:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/